# How to clear the sessionstorage on browser refresh , but this should not clear on click of browser back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to clear the session storage only on page refresh but not on
                           the browser back button click , or forward click 
                   want to implement this using angularjs/javascript

i am saving data in sessionstorage on click of back button so just i want to clear the same data on click of browser refresh button but it should not clear for back

i have tried

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    $window.sessionStorage.clear();
    // clearing the sessionstorage data
}

// but this one is clearing after clicking 2 times on refresh button

if (performance.navigation.type == 0) {
    $window.sessionStorage.clear();
    // clearing the sessionstorage data

}
// this one is clearing for back button as well ,
// tried onbeforeunload, onpopstate as well its not working its clearing for back button too

// please let me know how to implement this one, thanks in advance
// no jquery please
```

Comment: The question works fine for me, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You keep the page address that set the sessionStorage and then check it on the onload event. If they are the same, erase the sessionStorage contents.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("origin", window.location.href);
}
```

Then in the onload event:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.href == sessionStorage.getItem("origin")) {
        sessionStorage.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: surround above code with `if (typeof window !== "undefined")`

Comment: @AithaRanjeeth if this is about unit testing, you should know that by default the global object, whatever one it is, `global`, `chrome` or `window`, it should be mocked before any test cases are run. There are packages in npmjs.org that have that ready to use.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can achieve this on windows load and then clear the session storage or removing the key

```
$window.location.reload();
sessionStorage.clear();
```

> OR

```
// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
 $window.location.reload();    
 sessionStorage.removeItem('key');
```

Comment: only these two lines or do i need to bind any event/function and do i have to place this inside that ?

Comment: nothing just these two lines whenever you want to reload page

Comment: @vijayram just a small change please see

Comment: getting an error like $window.reload() is not a function

Answer (score 2):

You can use beforeunload

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
  sessionStorage.removeItem("{session}");
});
```

or set it as null

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("{session}",null);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$stateChangeStart` event

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, fromState){  
   if(toState.name === fromState.name){
     $window.sessionStorage.clear();
   }
})
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: unfortunately the application doesnt have any routing or thy havent used any ui-routier , or ng-route  still can i try this ??